# ActionEvent from a dynamic SWT button

Tags: java, button, swt

I'm working on a UI that will return results from a database. I'd like to put a button next to every row that is returned. I would like to manipulate the button based on it's state (true/false) and fire off a couple other events based on the state. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Each of my buttons has an id assigned to it but I'm not able to reference it when it is pressed.

```
private ArrayList<ExtButton>   btnList        = new ArrayList<ExtButton>();

/*
 * =======================================================
 * Inner Classes
 * =======================================================
 */
class ExtButton extends Composite
{
        private Button button;

        private int m_id;
        public ExtButton(Composite parent, int id) { 
            super(parent, SWT.NULL);
            setLayout(new FillLayout());
            button = new Button(this, SWT.TOGGLE | SWT.FLAT);
            button.setText("MyButton");
            m_id = id;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return m_id;
        }

        public Button getButton(){

            return button;
        }
}

...

   private void search(int resultSize)
{
    TableEditor[] rowEditor = new TableEditor[resultSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < resultSize; i++) {
        final TableItem item = new TableItem(resultTable, SWT.NONE);
        rowEditor[i] = new TableEditor(resultTable);
        ExtButton btnSelect = new ExtButton(resultTable, i);

        btnSelect.getButton().setText("Select");
        btnSelect.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, resultTable.getItemHeight());

        rowEditor[i].grabHorizontal = true;
        rowEditor[i].minimumHeight = btnSelect.getSize().y;
        rowEditor[i].minimumWidth = btnSelect.getSize().x;

        rowEditor[i].setEditor(btnSelect, item, 0);

        btnList.add(btnSelect);

        btnSelect.getButton().addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                    Integer btnId = ((ExtButton) event.getSource()).getParent().getId();
                    ExtButton button = btnList.get(btnId);
                    boolean btnState = ((ExtButton) event.getSource()).getButton().getSelection();
                    if (btnState == true)
                    {

                        button.getButton().setText("Select");
                    }
```

java:935: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                         Integer btnId = ((ExtButton)event.getSource()).getParent().getId();
[javac]                                                                                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method getId()
    [javac]   location: class Composite
    [javac] 1 error

Thanks!

Comment: `getParent()` returns a `Composite` which does not have a `getId()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getId` is a method of `ExtButton` rather than of `Composite` (returned by [`getParent`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#getParent%28%29))

```
Integer btnId = ((ExtButton)event.getSource()).getId();
```